# JPA to find not yet committed entities?

Tags: java, jpa, transactions

I recently ran into a pretty unexpected (to me) behavior of JPA (provided by EclipseLink).

Consider the following code:

```
public int myFunction() {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin(); // Application-managed EntityManager

    MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
    entity.setPrimaryKey(1);
    entityManager.persist(entity);

    entity = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, 1);

    if (entity == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    return 1;
}
```

The function WILL return 0 which means that I can not find a persisted entity before the transaction is closed.

**Questions.**
Is there any workarounds to be able to find not yet committed but persisted entities? If not, should I do some kind of caching on my own?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue using Hibernate 5.2.12 with both `persist()` and `merge()`. The JPA-API 2.1 documentation for `find()` is pretty clear about it: "If the entity instance is contained in the persistence context, it is returned from there.", and at least `merge()` says: "Merge the state of the given entity into the current persistence context." - So I too consider it quite surprising that `find()` implementations apparently only consider entities which were actually already sent to the DB (e.g. via `flush()`), which the user should really not have to care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EntityManager.flush() operation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting#Flush).